# x-forwarded-for headers lost when changing openshift route from http to https

Tags: nginx, http-headers, openshift

In Openshift 4.6, I have deployed an app that exposes an `nginx` service. When using `http`, I can see an IP in the nginx logs for the field `$http_x_forwarded_for`. Whenever I switch to `https`, the `$http_x_forwarded_for` header is missing (`-`).

The route config for `http`:

```yaml
spec:
  host: <my.host.com>
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-nginx
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 80-tcp
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

The route config for `https`:

```yaml
spec:
  host: <my.host.com>
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-nginx
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 443-tcp
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

Is there a way I can preserve the http headers for https requests?

Answer (score 3):

Not in `passthrough` mode, you can't!
Passthrough means the TLS traffic is *not* decrypted, so there is no chance the ingress controller (haproxy) is able to add or modify a header field.
Request forwarding is instead done on layer-4 (tcp) only.
You need to switch to `edge` or `reencrypt` termination mode for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes since v4.6 you should be able to do that. [Doc here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/ingress-operator.html#nw-using-ingress-forwarded_configuring-ingress)

For this you have to configure the ingress controller operator with the `httpHeaders.forwardedHeaderPolicy` parameter

However as you use a route of type`"passthrough"` As  HAProxy does not "touch" or modify in any way the request(ie decrypt and/or reencrypt) and route it "as-is" to the endpoint, no "x-forwarded-for" is added nor modified.

It works with a route of kind`"edge"`or`"reencrypt"`, depending on the parameter set on the ingress controller

So, if in "passthrough" mode your app does not receive the `"x-forwarded-for"` header,  it's because there is no such header on the request. Either your brwoser is directly hitting the OCP ingress controller (ie HAProxy) or your load balancer in front of OCP does not set this header

Comment: The `forwardedHeaderPolicy` doesn't seem to have an effect. With `edge` it works as expected. With `passthrough` the header is lost for some reason.

Comment: … The reason being that headers are part of the encrypted payload, which just gets *passed through*. So OpenShift is conceptually unable to set a header.